# How do I get the user home directory when running a Python script under sudo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using a Python SDK, I have developed an application that I run from a terminal, since some library I used required me to run this command on `sudo`.

Application creates a folder by creating a project name, and stores all data in the folde

In my case, when I run `sudo python app.py`, I am getting `root` directory instead of home directory `/home/<user_name>/`

In Python, how do I get the `/home/user/` ?

Please note that I only have one user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
os.path.expanduser('~{user}')
```

Where {user} is any user, in your case...user:

```
os.path.expanduser('~user')
```

Comment: Why won't you know which user directory you want to expand ahead of time?

Comment: You could iterate through each directory name under /home to get all users I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is `os.getlogin()` or even better `getpass.getlogin()`. According to the standard library documentation for `os.login()`:

> For most purposes, it is more useful to use getpass.getuser() since the latter checks the environment variables LOGNAME or USERNAME to find out who the user is, and falls back to pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0] to get the login name of the current real user id.

So if you want to pay attention to the environment variables, use `getpass.getlogin()` else prefere `os.getlogin()`

Answer (score -1):

```
cd /home/user && sudo python3 main.py
```

format, it will run in whatever directory you want.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. I am running the Python script only in my home directory. Like you said.